# Sum to K using python duplicate entries

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I am trying to prepare for a repetitive interview question. Given an array, find the pairs to get their sum as k. I am using python dictionary in this case instead of sorting method. The code is as follows:

```
def sumToK(lst):
  k = 16  # <- define the k here
  d = {} # build a dictionary 

  # build the hashmap key = val of lst, value = i
  for index, val in enumerate(lst):
    d[val] = index

# find the key; if a key is in the dict, and not the same index as the current key
for i, val in enumerate(lst):
  if (k-val) in d and d[k-val] != i:
    print k-val, val

a = [1,4,45,6,10,12,3]
sumToK(a)
```

I am getting duplicate values in the above way. How can I avoid it? Also, what if the array contains duplicate values. For example a = [1,4,45,6,10,12,4,8,8] Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing way too much work. You don't need to track indices at all, and you can do it in a single pass. Just keep a `set` of all numbers you've seen *so far*, and for each new number `n` you can check if its pair (`k - n`) is already in your set:

```
def find_pairs(numbers, k):
    seen = set()
    for n in numbers:
        if k - n in seen:
            print n, k - n
        seen.add(n)

a = [1,4,45,6,10,12,3]
find_pairs(a, 16)
# 10 6
# 12 4
```

If you want to prevent duplicate pairs from being printed, you can change the condition to also make sure `n not in seen`.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you only want to find the values and not their position in the list/array

```
import itertools as it
l = [1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
k = 4
s=[(a,b) for a,b in it.combinations(l,2) if a+b == k]
```

produces

```
[(1, 3), (1, 3), (2, 2)]
```

In case you want unique pairs

```
set(s)
```

gives

```
set([(1, 3), (2, 2)])
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an indentation error in your posted code.  The for loop right after the comment starting "find the key" needs to be indented.

By "duplicate values" I gather you mean that you are getting both the values 4, 12 and the values 12, 4.  You can eliminate this by making your test require that the first number be less than the second, for example.

As to eliminating duplicates, use a set instead of a dict.  Your code seems overly complicated.

```
def sumTo(k, lst):
    answer =set() 
    summands = set(lst)
    for small in range(k/2):
        large = k - small
        if small in summands and large in summands:
           answer.add((small, large))
    return answer
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Changed product to combination to avoid self-combinations

Using some ol' fashion functional python.

```
from itertools import combination
a = [1,4,45,6,10,12,4,8,8]
k = 16
set(
    map(
        lambda aa: tuple(sorted(aa)),
        filter(
            lambda (a1, a2): a1+a2 == k,
            combination(a, 2)
        )
    )
)

[Out]: set([(6, 10), (4, 12), (8, 8)])
```